# javascript, div buttons with if else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#b1').click(function() {
         $('#uch').toggle("slow");
    });
    $('#b2').click(function() {
         $('#uch2').toggle("slow");
    })
})
```

I'm not a programmer but somehow managed to make div buttons that opens another div when clicked but I cant manage how to make so that when I click on one button that opens div and then when I click on other button it opens div and hides previous div. I want to integrate it later to joomla template, but as I use jquery and all efforts with if not working maybe someone is clever then me. thanks in advance. I place here working fiddle too.
[fiddle example of my buttons](https://jsfiddle.net/elchinsolo/u28f6yeL/)

affter some usefull answers i reedited my code and managed to simplify it and added third button , now with extra css class everything seems pretty good but when i click already opened div it reappears as if looping.

[edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchinsolo/u28f6yeL/14/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#b1').click(function() {
$('.bats').hide("slow");
$('#uch').toggle("slow");
});
$('#b2').click(function() {
$('.bats').hide("slow");
$('#uch2').toggle("slow");
});
$('#b3').click(function() {
$('.bats').hide("slow");
$('#uch3').toggle("slow");
});
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `hide('slow')` on the other `uch` element on click of the button. Try this:

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
    $('#uch').toggle("slow");
    $('#uch2').hide("slow");
});
$('#b2').click(function() {
    $('#uch').hide("slow");
    $('#uch2').toggle("slow");
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u28f6yeL/2/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Change ID To Class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.b1').click(function() {
  $('.uch').hide();
    $(this).find('.uch').toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u28f6yeL/5/

Comment: in this way i lose smooth animation and it loops, somehow not what i really wanted , but i cached idea thx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for your problem:
change your JQuery code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#b1').click(function() {
     if($('#uch2').css('display') != 'none'){
          $('#uch2').toggle("slow");
};
    $('#uch').toggle("slow");
  });
  $('#b2').click(function() {
     if($('#uch').css('display') != 'none'){
          $('#uch').toggle("slow");
};
    $('#uch2').toggle("slow");
  });



});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u28f6yeL/6/)

Answer (score -1):

you can write a function which close the one is opend! than call them in your click-funktions before toggle the other.